# Manually validate server certificate in WinINet

Tags: security, ssl, wininet

I'm trying to implement manual self-signed SSL certificate validation to a WinINet client. I tried to approach it by calling `InternetQueryOption` with  `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE` or `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT` parameters, but both return some internal interpretation of server's certificate, none allows accessing raw certificate public key or at least thumbprimnt.

How am I supposed to validate certificate?...

Answer (score 5):

Additionaly to previous answer.
If you want to manualy check certificates with untrusted root(self signed for example), you need to

1. Set flags to ignore untrusted certificates

```cpp
// Open request before
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"), action, NULL, NULL, NULL, dwFlags, 0);
if (!hRequest) return GetLastError();

// set ignore options to request
DWORD dwFlags;
DWORD dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);
InternetQueryOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, (LPVOID)&dwFlags, &dwBuffLen);
dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
InternetSetOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, sizeof (dwFlags));
```

2. Send data request

```cpp
if (HttpSendRequest(hRequest, strHeaders, strHeaders.GetLength(), data, len)) {
```

3. And only after data request return we can view certificate info and check thumbprint.
   To get thumbprint we must use methods from cryptapi,
   so need to #include "WinCrypt.h" and add  crypt32.lib to linker

```cpp
PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT CertCtx=NULL;
DWORD cbCertSize = sizeof(&CertCtx);

// Get certificate chain information
if (InternetQueryOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT, (LPVOID)&CertCtx, &cbCertSize))
{
    PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT pChainContext=CertCtx;

    CERT_SIMPLE_CHAIN *simpleCertificateChainWithinContext = NULL;
    for (int i=0; i<pChainContext->cChain; i++)
    {
        simpleCertificateChainWithinContext=pChainContext->rgpChain[i];
        
        // We can check any certificates from chain, but if selfsigned it will be single
        for (int simpleCertChainIndex = 0; simpleCertChainIndex < simpleCertificateChainWithinContext->cElement; simpleCertChainIndex++)
        {
            // get the CertContext from the array
            PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = simpleCertificateChainWithinContext->rgpElement[simpleCertChainIndex]->pCertContext;
            
            // Public key can be getted from
            //  (((*((*pCertContext).pCertInfo)).SubjectPublicKeyInfo).PublicKey).pbData
            // but better to use thumbprint to check

            // CERT_HASH_PROP_ID - is a thumbprint
            BYTE thumbprint[1024];
            DWORD len = 1024;
            if (CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_HASH_PROP_ID, thumbprint, &len)) {
                //
                // !!! HERE WE CAN CHECK THUMPRINT WITH TRUSTED(PREVIOUSLY SAVED)
                // and return error, or accept request output.
                //
            }
        }
    }
    
    // important! Free the CertCtx
    CertFreeCertificateChain(CertCtx);
}
```

4. Why use thumbprint to compare certificate?
   There three interesting fields in certificate to compare:
   Serial number, Public key, Thumbprint.
   Serial number is just unique number  chosen by the CA which issued the certificate,
   public key good solution, but thumbprint is hash computed over the complete certificate
   (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-number-and-thumbprint)

Answer (score 0):

WinInet will already validate returned certificate's domain name matches the certificate and the certificate chain is trusted if you set INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE when calling HttpOpenRequest.

Few things you can do afterwards:

1. Use INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT's lpszIssuerInfo to compare returned domain name and certificate name match to parent certificate that is expected.
2. Parse out Issuer name from lpszIssuerInfo and call to CertFindCertificateInStore to get certificate context pointer.
3. Get and validate certificate chain using CertGetCertificateChain and certificate context pointer, such as comparing thumbprints of issuing certificates, but not the actual certificate itself to my knowledge.

For future reference, from MSDN: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385328(VS.85).aspx". If IE8.0 is installed, there is a new option that exposes server's certificate chain.

INTERNET_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT
105

Retrieves the server’s certificate-chain context as a duplicated PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT. You may pass this duplicated context to any Crypto API function which takes a PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT. You must call CertFreeCertificateChain on the returned PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT when you are done with the certificate-chain context.

Version:  Requires Internet Explorer 8.0.

Comment: I haven't been working with this issue for awhile, but from what I could recall, I needed to make wininet work with privately self-issued certificate. So, the certificate will not be in store, and chain will not be trusted. I wanted to verify trust myself, programmatically. As I recall, WinINet was not giving access to the raw certificate or thumbprint, but to the subject name and issuer name and such. Anyone can generate certificate with given subject name or issuer name.