# INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT

Tags: https, certificate

The title option NTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT is mentioned in your entry [Manually validate server certificate in WinINet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732107/manually-validate-server-certificate-in-wininet). However I tried to use it with CInternetSession session with QueryOption like this and failed:

```
BYTE lpBuffer[2048];

DWORD lpdwBufferLength = sizeof(lpBuffer);

BOOL resQueryOption = session.QueryOption((DWORD)**INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT**,  lpBuffer,&lpdwBufferLength);  //error FALSE returned

DWORD erro1r = GetLastError(); //error! **ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE**
```

The same with ::InternetQueryOption. What is wrong? How can I use it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I sent query too early, the correct way it not send after GetHttpConnection and not after OpenRequest, but only after SendRequest.
So the correct order is

```
CInternetSession session(_T("something"));

CHttpConnection *pConnection =  session.GetHttpConnection(
      strHost, flags, ipUsedPort, _T(""), _T(""));

CHttpFile *pFile = pConnection->OpenRequest(
      mode, "url", NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE);  

res = res && pFile->SendRequest(
      strHeaders, (LPVOID) (LPCTSTR) sbody.c_str(), sbody.length());

INTERNET_CERTIFICATE_INFO certificateInfo; 
DWORD certInfoLength = sizeof(INTERNET_CERTIFICATE_INFO); 
BOOL resQueryResult = pFile->QueryOption(
      (DWORD)INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT,  &certificateInfo,&certInfoLength);  

DWORD le = GetLastError();
```