# Https client authentication with Wininet, using a non-persistant root certificate

Tags: c++, authentication, ssl, https, wininet

I'm communicating by https with a server that needs client authentication.

To make it work I had to import the server root certificate into the Windows' global certificate store using the *Microsoft Management Console* (mms).

But I'm trying to make it run silently.

So my question is:

**How to tell Wininet that a given certificate is the root one, so it can use it to check the whole certificate chain?**

(without user handling, nor administrator privilege, nor system level registration)

More details:

I have (a) the certificate + (b) private key of my client.

I have (c) the root certificate of the server.

I built a pfx file containing (a) and (b) :

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem   -inkey client-key.pem -certfile root.pem -out  test.pfx`

Now I can use  **test.pfx**  to build a certificate store **CS** (using `PFXImportCertStore`).

During the building of my request, I set all the certificates from the **CS** (using `InternetSetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT)`)

Here is a very minimalist extract of my code:

```cs
CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB blob ;
blob.pbData = ...pointer to a buffer containing test.pfx
blob.cbData = ...size of this buffer
HCERTSTORE cs = PFXImportCertStore( &blob,L"pw",PKCS12_NO_PERSIST_KEY ) ;
HINTERNET ses = InternetOpen("test",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0) ;
HINTERNET con = InternetConnect( ses,"server",4444,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,NULL ) ;
HINTERNET req = HttpOpenRequest( con,"POST",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE,NULL ) ;
PCCERT_CONTEXT pc = CertEnumCertificatesInStore( cs,0 ) ;
for (; pc ; pc = CertEnumCertificatesInStore( cs,pc ))
    InternetSetOption( req,INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT,(void*)pc,sizeof( CERT_CONTEXT )) ;
HttpSendRequest( req,NULL,0,NULL,0 ) ;
```

But it doesn't work as it is.

I have to insert the root certificate (c) in the windows' certificates store.

Furthermore, the certificate (c) inserted within the pfx file is useless.

I may omit it in my `openssl` command line.

Since I want it to run silently and this root certificate is used just once for this lone request, I wonder if it possible to tag it as *root* (at the `PFXImportCertStore` or the `InternetSetOption` step) ?

PS *I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 / Windows 10 x64.*

PPS *This is the sequel of my previous post: [Client authentication (certificat + private key) using WinInet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297953/).*

Comment: Import it programmatically (admin)

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/732107/150978